# Restrict attachments in media library to only posts in Wordpress

Tags: image, wordpress, media

i'm trying to restrict the media library so when you click attach for an image that is already uploaded but not attached yet the pop up that shows all the posts and pages will only show posts. This is for wordpress 3.5

Comment: Have you tried any implementation..?

Comment: no, i haven't found any information about how to do this any place. so i have no idea how to implement it.